# Javascript array of objects will not sort, despite setting sort function

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects, in which each contains several numerical values. Here is the layout of the object:

```
{
v: [],
cm: 0
}
```

This is the definition of the sort function:

```
registry.sort(function(a,b) {return (a.cm > b.cm) ? 1 : ((b.cm > a.cm) ? -1 : 0);} );
```

When I run the sort function, it does nothing whatsoever, just leaves the array the way it was. I am new to js, but as far as I can tell, everything should be working. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks

EDIT: here is the smallest example I can extract

```
var registry = [];
registry.sort(function(a,b) {return (a.cm > b.cm) ? 1 : ((b.cm > a.cm) ? -1 : 0);} );

var draw = function() {
//various other function calls that add values to the registry array
registry[0] = {v:[0,0,0], cm:3}; //just to have something to use in the variable
registry[1] = {v:[0,0,0], cm:2};
debug(registry[0], registry[1]);
registry.sort();
debug(registry[0], registry[1]);
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to post more information. There's no issue with the code you provided.

Comment: I was thinking more in line of a full working example. In your new code, you're now calling `.sort()` without passing a function. Maybe you could simply post the code that isn't working, including the data. For some reason, you're leaving parts out.

Comment: Sorry to do this to you, but...
https://www.khanacademy.org/cs/very-simple-3d-engine-is-not-entirely-functional/1936582188

Comment: Well, I'm sorry to do *this* to you, but... http://sscce.org

Comment: you can't declare registry.sort(..) and then use the same sort comparator like that...

Comment: ...what? You need to post an example of the original array, the expected output, and the block of code that isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sort() is not a configuration. When you call it, it does the sort. You can do this:

```
var comparator = function(a,b) {return (a.cm > b.cm) ? 1 : ((b.cm > a.cm) ? -1 : 0);}
for (var i = 0; i < regPos; i++) {
    debug(registry[i], "eah");        
}
registry.sort(comparator);
registry.reverse();
for (var i = 0; i < regPos; i++) {
    debug(registry[i]);        
}
```

Or simply

```
var comparator = function(a,b) {return a.cm - b.cm;}
```

Comment: Ohhh I get it. I would have had to declare the sort function inline while calling the sort function, as opposed to just "defining" it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code below will sort the array "points" which has a similar structure... not sure if this is an exact match for your data though.

```
var points = [{v:[1,2,3],cm:40},{v:[2], cm:100},{v:[], cm:1},{cm:5,v:[]},{v:[3],cm:25},{cm:10}];
points.sort(function(a,b) {return (a.cm - b.cm);});

for (x in points) {
    console.log(points[x]);
}
```

Are you sure the "cm" field is defined for every record in your array?